Is it legal to photograph a nosy neighbour?
If I had an intimidating neighbour that frequently stood their side of our garden fence staring at me and my family whilst we were in the garden (or even at times in the house), would it be legal for me to capture the behaviour on camera (either still or video)? What if, rather than in their garden, they were standing in their house watching us through their window?
Does the answer to this change if the photo/video is taken with CCTV rather than a handheld device?
In the above case, would I need to stop recording and/or delete any photos/footage if requested?

Do you know the term "reasonable expectation of privacy"

I'm familiar with the term, yes, but wondering how it applies in this situation, specifically in the UK (there are plenty of questions and examples centred around the US).

united-kingdom
Imagine a range of possible actions, from

(A) you doing nothing else with regard to your neighbour but on one occasion taking one photograph of him staring over your fence, to
(Z) you setting up multi-device round-the-clock audiovisual surveillance of the neighbour's property.

In the range between A and Z there is a variety of actions. At A you're doing nothing unlawful; a little further along, even if your behaviour might be unlawful on paper, it's unlikely the police will be interested, it's unlikely to be practical to pursue in civil proceedings. As you proceed towards the extreme end your legal risks increase. At Z, on the face of it you are committing torts (civil wrongs) and criminal offences.
If on the face it you are committing torts or criminal offences, the purpose of your actions may provide you a defence or exemption. E.g. perhaps you are gathering evidence for your civil or criminal complaint about the neighbour's behaviour - this is a statutory defence against a harassment claim (civil or criminal - see below).
Here are three things you are not wholly legally free to do on or from your own property:

to pursue a 'course of conduct' that amounts to the 'harassment' or 'stalking' of your neighbour (the Protection from Harassment Act 1977, which can be a tort or criminal offence)
to cause a substantial and unreasonable interference with your neighbour's right to enjoyment of his property (the tort of 'private nuisance' at common law)
to record images, video or (in particular) audio of people beyond the boundaries of your own property, even incidentally (in this context you can't rely on the domestic or household activity exemption under data protection law - people have argued that you should be able to, to some extent, but right or wrong the fact is that some courts have ruled otherwise - an example below - and that is why I say you can't rely on the exemption)

Harassment or stalking
As well as the definition of harassment at section 1 Protection from Harassment Act 1977 we have guidance from Mr Justice Simon in Dowson & Ors v Chief Constable of Northumbria Police (Rev 1) [2010] EWHC 2612 (QB):


I turn then to a summary of what must be proved as a matter of law in order for the claim in harassment to succeed.

(1) There must be conduct which occurs on at least two occasions, [section 7(3) PHA 1997]

Doing nothing other than taking one photograph cannot amount to 'a course of conduct', therefore it can't be harassment. Doing more than taking one photograph could amount to a course of conduct - it depends.

(2) which is targeted at the claimant,
(3) which is calculated in an objective sense to cause alarm or distress [section 7(2) PHA 1997], and
(4) which is objectively judged to be oppressive and unacceptable.

As usual, "objective" and "objectively" here mean the claimant (the accuser) must persuade the court the average or ordinary person would believe this.

(5) What is oppressive and unacceptable may depend on the social or working context in which the conduct occurs.
(6) A line is to be drawn between conduct which is unattractive and unreasonable, and conduct which has been described in various ways: 'torment' of the victim, 'of an order which would sustain criminal liability'.

Section 2A(3) PHA provides "examples of acts or omissions which, in particular circumstances, are ones associated with stalking", including:

(g) watching or spying on a person.

Section 1(3) PHA specifies three defences:

(3) Subsection (1) or (1A) does not apply to a course of conduct if the person who pursued it shows—
(a) that it was pursued for the purpose of preventing or detecting
crime,
(b) that it was pursued under any enactment or rule of law or to comply with any condition or requirement imposed by any person under any enactment, or
(c) that in the particular circumstances the pursuit of the course of conduct was reasonable.

You'll notice the neighbour's behaviour might be harassment.
Nuisance
The law of private nuisance is intended to maintain a balance "between the right of the occupier to do what he likes with his own, and the right of his neighbour not to be interfered with" (Sedleigh-Denfield v O'Callaghan [1940] AC 880, 903 (Lord Wright)).
Looking into someone's land could give rise to a tort of nuisance (again you'll notice this could apply to the neighbour). Fearn & Ors v Board of Trustees of the Tate Gallery [2023] UKSC 4), paragraph 16:


In this case we are concerned, not with a sight to which an occupier of land is subjected when looking out, but with the interference caused by people constantly looking in. Leaving the actual facts of this case aside for the moment, it is not difficult to imagine circumstances in which an ordinary person would find such visual intrusion an intolerable interference with their freedom to use and enjoy their property. A colourful illustration is provided by a mediaeval case heard at the London Assize of Nuisance in 1341: see Misc Roll DD: 5 Nov 1339 - 15 Dec 1346, number 365. According to the case record:

“The [plaintiff] complains that John le Leche, fishmonger, has a leaden watch-tower (garritam) upon the wall of his tenement adjoining hers in the same par[ish] upon which he and his household (familiares) stand daily, watching the private affairs of the pl[aintiff] and her servants. The def[endant], present upon the land before the mayor and aldermen, admits the nuisance, and freely undertakes to remove it within 40 days subject to the customary penalty.”

It is not a good defence for the defendant to say the claimant could do something (e.g. pull the curtains, close the blinds, stay out of the garden) to avoid the consequences of the defendant's nuisance, because it places the burden of mitigating or stopping the nuisance on the victim of the nuisance instead of the person causing the nuisance (paragraph 83).
Data protection law
Images, video and audio recordings of people are 'personal data' of those 'data subjects'. If you the householder capture this personal data originating outside the boundary of your private property, e.g. people in the street or someone else's property, then the General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) and the Data Protection Act 2018 may apply as you can't reliably claim the domestic or household activty exemption in Article 2(c) GDPR:


This Regulation does not apply to the processing of personal data: ...

(c) by a natural person in the course of a purely personal or household activity;

See Guidance on the use of domestic CCTV on gov.uk. Whether the regulator will enforce the law is another matter, the ICO has stated that it's unlikely to take enforcement action against householders, but the courts have ruled in favour of some private complainants.
This doesn't necessarily make your behaviour unlawful. In such circumstances you become a 'data controller' and you're obliged to:

make an effort to minimise the intrusion on the privacy of others
be open and transparent about your behaviour, e.g. inform your neighbours about it, put up signs that recording is taking place
have a 'lawful basis' for it (there are six)
store the data for no longer than is necessary
be aware of data protection rights and facilitate the exercise of those rights

and so on. If you don't do those things you increase your risk.
Again, taking one photograph is likely nothing but it is risky to mount several cameras that cover the neighbour's property - it's worse if the cameras are deliberately aimed at the neighbour's property. Audio recordings are considered particularly intrusive.
An example case
An illustrative case is Fairhurst vs Woodard - not precedent-setting because it was heard by County Court, however it is relevant to the three items above. Claimant Fairhurst brought a claim for harassment, nuisance and breach of the GDPR and DPA against her neighbour, defendant Woodard.
Woodard had set up a floodlight and sensor, two Ring spotlight cameras, a Ring doorbell and a Nest camera pointing towards a car park or street respectively. The Ring devices could record audio as well as video.


The Claimant’s case in broad summary is that the Defendant has consistently failed to be open and honest with the Claimant about the Cameras, has unnecessarily and unjustifiably invaded her privacy by his use of the Cameras and has intimidated her when challenged about that use, and that this amounts to:

i) a nuisance; and
ii) breach of the Data Protection Act 2018 and Regulations thereto (“DPA 2018”); and
iii) a course of conduct designed to harass the Claimant contrary to the Protection from Harassment Act 1997 (“PHA 1997”)

Ultimately:


The Claimant’s claims in harassment and breach of the DPA 2018 succeed.

The Claimant’s claims in nuisance are dismissed



The nuisance claim failed partly because the court was aware of Fearn & Ors v Board of Trustees of the Tate Gallery at the Court of Appeal stage, when it held that "mere overlooking from one property to another is not capable of giving rise to a cause of action in private nuisance". But, as mentioned above, on appeal the Supreme Court found that overlooking from one property to another is capable of giving rise to a cause of action in private nuisance. Poor timing.
(The other part of the nuisance claim was that a light could cause a nuisance and this was agreed to be a valid cause of action. However, in these particular circumstances  the court found the light was not an undue interference with the claimant's use or enjoyment of her property.)

The nuisance medieval example would be applicable if the OP was climbing over the fence to film the neighbour (vs filming what is visible without special effort to see more). But the question does not imply climbing over the fence or otherwise making effort to see more than the neighbour would already be aware is easily seen.

@Greendrake It has nothing to do with climbing over a fence. The medieval circumstances and Fearn circumstances are involve people standing in one property looking into another property, and in Fearn the Supreme Court held that could give rise to a nuisance.

As per your quote, back then it was "...leaden watch-tower (garritam) upon the wall.." which they stood upon (presumably went up there specifically to see what they could not see behind the wall). Nowadays that would be tantamount to climbing over a fence, wouldn't it be?

@Greendrake it doesn't seem to me that standing upon a wall is "tantamount to" climbing over a wall.

There are a few laws that may be relevant:

the tort of invasion of privacy relates to Article 8 of the HRA https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/42/schedule/1/part/I/chapter/7
what this means is that if you invade someone's privacy the court may, following legal action from the injured party, injunct you or award damages
this is not a criminal action, so it is nothing to do with the police.

It is possible for either party to argue that the crime of harassment is being committed https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1997/40/section/1. To the extent that either party alleges that the other is committing the offence of harassment, any alleged invasion of privacy is likely to be defeated for the reason of "for the prevention of disorder or crime", i.e. that you are filming the alleged 'harassment'.
Secondly, there are rules under the Data Protection Act 2018/GDPR. Here there is a general exception to GDPR for domestic purposes. https://ico.org.uk/for-organisations/uk-gdpr-guidance-and-resources/exemptions/a-guide-to-the-data-protection-exemptions/#:~:text=Domestic%20purposes%20%E2%80%93%20personal%20data%20processed,outside%20the%20UK%20GDPR's%20scope.
Note that photography is also generally presumed to be legal.  https://www.met.police.uk/advice/advice-and-information/ph/photography-advice#:~:text=Freedom%20to%20photograph%20and%20film,photographing%20incidents%20or%20police%20personnel.

As a rule of thumb, if the neighbour can reasonably expect to be seen by whoever is looking in his direction from your property, you can film him. For video only, CCTV or handheld does not matter. Audio can be recorded if you are there recording it and he is (or should be) aware that you are there, not just your device.
To certain extent this rule applies even if he is inside the house. This extent extends to the level of detail that can be seen by an unequipped human eye. That said, it would certainly be invasion of his privacy to use tele lens or other special equipment that enables to capture what he would not expect a random passer-by (or a guest to your property) to see. But if your equipment only captures what you can see just standing there, he would not succeed with invasion of privacy claims because he should be aware of how much a naked eye can see from outside, and if that is too much, he should use curtains etc.

would I need to stop recording and/or delete any photos/footage if requested?

Only if you've recorded what he could not reasonably expect to be seen.

This isn't true of the UK.

@Lag Write your answer, and if it convinces me that this one is wrong, I will delete it.

I'm writing an answer. While I'm doing that, perhaps you will provide evidence to support your answer.

@Lag I don't feel like proving this answer is correct, but I am open to hear proof it is wrong.

And then there is the corollary:  "is there a law that prohibits X?"  "no, there is no law prohibiting X."  "can you provide evidence to prove your assertion?"

"I don't feel like proving this answer is correct" That's not how this site works.

@TripeHound It works that way just fine. We share what we know here, and we don't owe any proof to anyone (although of course we provide it if we feel like it).

But have you shared anything you know? It seems like you're just sharing random guesses.

@bdb484 That is no guesses but knowledge I have accumulated from various sources over the years. I am lazy to search and cite those sources, and my memory by all means may be inaccurate. But, until proven wrong, I am confident in this knowledge to the extent that I would act upon it if I was in the OP's situation.

Eh. I think I'd disagree that what you're describing constitutes "knowledge." It's just things you heard and believed without verifying them.

But that's how 90+% of knowledge works.  How much of what you learned in school or watched on the nightly news have you undertaken to personally verify?

I have undertaken to personally verify basically every answer I post here.

@bdb484 Good on you, but that doesn't empower you to redefine what is commonly referred to as "knowledge".
